# Migrating Tumblr to octopress (Jekyll) - in wrong directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I'm trying to migrate a blog from Tumblr to Octopress.

When I run in the octopress directory

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll/migrators/tumblr"; Jekyll::Tumblr.process("http://example.org", format="md")'
```

It starts running but then complains about what folder it's in

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:27:in `read': No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/../_posts/tumblr/2012-08-28-how-to-add-your-picture-to-google-results.md (Errno::ENOENT)
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:27:in `read_yaml'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/post.rb:39:in `initialize'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/tumblr.rb:124:in `new'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/tumblr.rb:124:in `block in rewrite_urls_and_redirects'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/tumblr.rb:119:in `map'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/tumblr.rb:119:in `rewrite_urls_and_redirects'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/tumblr.rb:30:in `process'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: have you found an answer to this ? I have the exact same problem...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty fix that worked for me (doesn't apply if you don't have root access, obviously), but it will get the job done.

Here's your error message for reference:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:27:in `read': \
    No such file or directory - \
   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/../_posts/tumblr/2012-08-28-how-to-add-your-picture-to-google-results.md (Errno::ENOENT)
```

The full path in the exception is:

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/../_posts/tumblr/2012-08-28-how-to-add-your-picture-to-google-results.md

Here's the solution:

```
 1. cd to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/
 2. cd ..
 3. ln -s %{DIRECTORY_WHERE__posts_LIVES}
 4. Re-run your migration command
```

Just creating this symlink fixes the issue but it's an obvious and total hack.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/_posts/tumblr/2012-08-28-how-to-add-your-picture-to-google-results.md` exist? If not maybe you could just move your posts to that folder first, just as a simply workaround.